# Why does C++ think 8^1/3 = 1?

Tags: c++, pow

I was testing the pow() function in c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << pow(8,(1/3)) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

For some reason, this returns 1. Why does this happen?

Comment: Check for "integer division". Try to print the result of `1/3`

Comment: Because C++ knows what it's doing.

Comment: Why did you test the `pow` function but didn't bother testing what `1/3` is?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because `1/3` is evaluated in integers. The result of the division is `0`, so `pow(x, 0)` produces `1`.

Change the division to division in doubles like this:

```
cout << pow(8,(1.0/3)) << endl; // prints 2 as expected
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/qFSLOz)

Answer (score 2):

1/3 produces an integer result of 0

Answer (score 1):

when you use integers as your input to the pow() function the computer truncates the output.  If you input floating point numbers the error will be corrected

pow(8, 1/3) = 1

pow(8.0, 1.0/3) = 2

Comment: Integer division results are truncated, not floored.

Comment: Absolutely correct. the terminology of truncation vs flooring is more correct even though the result is the same

Comment: The result is the same in this case, but not for negative numbers.

Comment: Yes, or course i mean for this example the result is the same.  A negative number truncation would not floor.  The answer has been modified to use the correct term.